# flume - flume.root.logger=DEBUG,console only logs INFO level log statements

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I installed Flume 1.4.0-cdh4.7.0 in CentOS (cloudera VM)

I ran the following command to start the flume

**flume-ng agent -n agent-name -c conf -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.looger=DEBUG,console**

but it is only writing the default (INFO) level to the console. Cannot figure out why?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution. For now I am changing the log level inside the class to DEBUG level and able to see it in the taskattempt log

Answer (score 5):

There is a typo in your command line:

```
flume-ng agent -n agent-name -c conf -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.looger=DEBUG,console
```

It says **root.looger** in stead of ***root.logger*** and so your command line option is overridden by something in the log4j.propeties file

Answer (score 3):

The **-Dflume.root.logger** property overrides the root logger in **conf/log4j.properties** to use the console appender. If you didn't override the root logger, everything would still work, but the output would be going to a file **log/flume.log** instead. Of course, you can also just edit the **conf/log4j.properties** file and change the flume.root.logger property (or anything else you like).

Answer (score 1):

It wont work if flume's bin directory (which contains flume-ng shell) is placed on PATH. You have to start it from flume's root dir, and place inside **conf/log4j.properties** the desired level for logging, in this case DEBUG. 
Then and only then it will log into file or console on the desired level.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this to get debug level info in console.

> bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n agent